# Android: using custom widgets' implementation globally

Tags: android, xml, fonts, android-widget, android-theme

I'm developing an simple Android game for learning purposes and i came across such problem:
I wish to implement custom font for all TextViews, Buttons and maybe some other widgets, so after long searching i figured out it's impossible to do so via XML.

The ony way is to load it programmaticaly (sorry for my poor grammar). 
So I implemented custom widgets for each one to do this operation on instatiation.
But, the problem is, i don't want to replace all Widgets' declaration in XMLs with full names of my classes.

So I came up with declaring custom theme and overriding widgets' styles, but I just can't find a way to pass there my custom classes.
"android:name" attribute doesn't work (by the description it should...)
and "class" attribute which is proposed to me by Eclipse as one of variants is not found (somehow...).

So basically the question is: 
How do I make all TextViews (for example) declared in XMLs as TextView, use my custom implementation.

Thanks for your attention.